# How can I output the most recent mysql $row value after it changes without reloading page?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a user settings page where the user changes their name via ajax and calls an update script that works great. The problem is I include a separate sidebar file which echos the current name in the database, but doesn't change until you reload the page because it's a separate sidebar.php include.

```
included sidebar.php within settings.php page

<h2 id="profile-name">
    <?php 
    if(!$userRow['name']){
      echo "You";
    }else{
      echo ucfirst($userRow['name']); 
    }
    ?>
</h2>

//form starts


 <form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">

     Name: <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder= "<?php echo $userRow['name']; ?>" name="name" value="<?php echo $userRow['name']; ?>"><br>

 <input class="btn btn-default" id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form"> <span id="status"></span>
     </form>

//ajax works fine and updates database

function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){

  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append( "name", _("name").value );
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open( "POST", "update_name.php" );
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
      if(ajax.responseText == "success"){

      } else {
       // _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
       alert("saved");
        _("mybtn").disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
  ajax.send( formdata );
}
```

Just can't figure out how to get the sidebar to update without reloading the page. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Well, the conventional "solution" is to use AJAX - it is also what appears to have been attempted and is a tag (so why even ask that as a question?). Find out which part "isn't working" and fix it. Do this by systematically checking assumptions using tools - PHP error log, Browser console log, Browser network monitor, DOM inspection, etc. After doing this research it should be possible to either solve the issue or come up with a very refined question about an identified problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did research. I temporary fixed it by changing the inner html of the sidebar when the ajax call is complete.

Comment: That's awesome! JSON is often returned via XHR and then the page content is updated by manipulating the DOM piece-wise (eg. the content of a span might be replaced) instead of replacing everything. This generally would be done by having a secondary page specific to the JSON-returning query; it doesn't need to worry about any of the surrounding HTML.